# sed to remove a user in svn access control list

Tags: linux, svn, sed

Filename: stackgroup.acl

```
[groups]
stackoverflow=linus,steve,bill,adrian
stackexchange=charlie,darwin,carol,kelly
```

I need an sed code that could remove a user whether it's in the start of the line, or the end of it.

Here's what I got so far:

```
sed 's/\(.*=*\)linus,\(.*\)/\1\2/g'
sed 's/\(.*=*\)steve,\(.*\)/\1\2/g'
sed 's/\(.*=*\),adrian\(.*\)/\1\2/g'
```

as you can see, the middle one is fine, but the first and last user will leave an additional comma.

I even tried using regex:

```
sed 's/\(.*=*\),\?linus,\?\(.*\)/\1\2/g'
```

or

```
sed 's/\(.*=*\),*linus,*\(.*\)/\1\2/g'
```

but it's not working.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have to use sed? You could do this in Python with something like `",".join(x for x in names.split(",") if x != "linus")`

Comment: The script is written in linux bash script, so I thought I just extend the functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two expressions, the 2nd one takes care of the edge case where the name is directly after the `=`

```
#!/bin/bash

user="linus"
sed "s/,\?$user//;s/=,/=/" stackgroup.acl
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
v1=charlie;v2=darwin;v3=kelly

sed s'/'"$v1"',\?\|,'"$v1"'$//' <<<"stackexchange=charlie,darwin,carol,kelly"
stackexchange=darwin,carol,kelly
sed s'/'"$v2"',\?\|,'"$v2"'$//' <<<"stackexchange=charlie,darwin,carol,kelly"
stackexchange=charlie,carol,kelly
sed s'/'"$v3"',\?\|,'"$v3"'$//' <<<"stackexchange=charlie,darwin,carol,kelly"
stackexchange=charlie,darwin,carol
sed s'/'"$v3"',\?\|,'"$v3"'$//' <<<"stackexchange=kelly"
stackexchange=
```